# how to Receive Broadcast Receiver action in my activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hi I am showing all installed application in my device in to application but if i install any new application I need to know from my broadcast receiver activity but I'm unable to get its action to my MainActivity class please suggest

this is manifiest file where i register receiver class:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".NewAppReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

below code of my BrodcastReceiver class:

```
public class NewAppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = "Broadcast intent detected "
                + intent.getAction();

  Toast.makeText(context, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}
```

I want to receive action of receive in my mainActivity without Intent calling

Comment: Have your `BroadcastReceiver` post an event on an event bus (greenrobot's EventBus, `LocalBroadcastManager`, etc.), which your activity can then subscribe to in order to find out about the event. Also, bear in mind that your `<receiver>` will not work on Android 8.0+, as those broadcasts are no longer available for receivers registered in the manifest.

Comment: Thank u @commansWare can u suggest me another way or snippet for this because I'm new in Android thank you in advance

Comment: I cover event buses in my book. Version 5.8 of my book is a few years old, but [it is free for you to download and read](https://commonsware.com/Android/4-2-free).